# How to create div box with wings or tabs with css

Tags: css

I am trying to create a div that looks like that. See the top and bottom with the little tab. I cannot figure out how to do this, it is a "design" thing. I have tried to use the :before :after CSS to create this but no luck. Any ideas?

Added code below. You can see it comes to a point, any way to have it flat?

[image: Box with tabs]

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}


.container.tab-top:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -15px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.container.tab-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container tab-top tab-bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code here, even better make a codepen and add the link here.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry I posted too quick and had to step away. Posted with code. Main this is the flat top / bottom of the bump outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `borders` for this. Create a pseudo element and use `border-radius`.

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}


.container.tab-top:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 7px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: black;
  border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
  top: -7px;
}

.container.tab-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 7px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: black;
  border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
  bottom: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container tab-top tab-bottom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using perspective and rotation:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px
}

.container.tab-top:before,
.container.tab-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left:15%;
  right:15%;
  height:30px;
  background:#000;

}
.container.tab-top:before {
  bottom:100%;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(50deg);
}

.container.tab-bottom:after {
  top:100%;
  border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container tab-top tab-bottom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Trapezoid Shape css like:

```
#trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```css
.box {
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px solid pink;
position: relative;
}
.box::before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
border-bottom: 10px solid pink;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 100px;
top: -10px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
.box::after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
border-top: 10px solid pink;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 100px;
bottom: -10px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

```
I used as before after css of a div.
```